# Cannot destroy items in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following code

```
def destroy
  @demand_site = DemandSite.find(params[:id])
  @demand_site.destroy
  flash[:success] = "Demand Site destroyed."
  redirect_to demand_sites_path
end
```

To destroy an item in my sql table. Here is my migrate-file

```
def change
  create_table :demand_sites do |t|
    t.integer :site_id
    t.float :demand_quantity
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

When I want to destroy an item the following error occurs:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: translinks.demand_site_id: SELECT "translinks".* FROM "translinks"  WHERE "translinks"."demand_site_id" = 14

where the id number changes. I can add new items and change them, but not destroy them afterwards. When I take a look in to the SQL table it shows me the correct columns and ids. I can delete them manually but not via rails.

How can I solve this problem?

The view page

```
<% @demand_sites.each do |demand_site| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= demand_site.site.codename %></td>
    <td><%= demand_site.site.name %></td>
    <td><%= best_in_place demand_site, :demand_quantity, :type => :input%></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', demand_site %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Update', edit_demand_site_path(demand_site) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', demand_site, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Post your view page in which the link to delete action is mentioned.

Comment: In controller you have a method destroy but in the view page,it is written as delete

Comment: The method written in view file is the `HTTP method(verb)` and not the controller's action. It is written correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `translink` table must have a column `demand_site_id`. Create a new migration that adds this column to the table and run the migration.